# woocommerce admin product search: only search by 1 meta, and product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, admin

I want to search the products in woocommerce in the admin only by meta OR title. How do I achieve this?

I already have added the custom meta by putting this in my functions.php:

```
function m_request_query( $query_vars ) {

global $typenow;
global $wpdb;
global $pagenow;

if ( 'product' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {
        $search_term            = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );
        $meta_key               = '_barcode';
        $post_types             = array( 'product', 'product_variation' );
        $search_results         = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id, posts.post_parent as parent_id FROM {$wpdb->posts} posts LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS postmeta ON posts.ID = postmeta.post_id WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '{$meta_key}' AND postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s AND posts.post_type IN ('" . implode( "','", $post_types ) . "') ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC",
                '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_term ) . '%'
            )
        );
        $product_ids            = wp_parse_id_list( array_merge( wp_list_pluck( $search_results, 'product_id' ), wp_list_pluck( $search_results, 'parent_id' ) ) );
        $query_vars['post__in'] = array_merge( $product_ids, $query_vars['post__in'] );
    }

    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'request', 'm_request_query', 20 );
```

But now I want to add the product name to it, and exclude everything else. I think it searches the description.

How do I do this?